# Class supporting ms Access database file connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any c# class that supports connecting to ms Access database ? I need to execute one command on this database , but I have only found a class SqlCommand and SqlConnection that supports only SQLServer .
I don't have installed SQL server and I can't install It.

Comment: You're wanting OleDbCommand and OleDbConnection which is part of the System.Data.OleDb namespace.

Comment: Did you try maybe searching for "connect to access db c#" because there's a *lot* of information on it?

Comment: If I would have better Internet connection and repaired my keyboard, yes  i Will do it. The problem is that I can connect with Access db in aspx webpages but I can't connect to It in the cs source files.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Data.OleDb;
```

is I think what you're looking for. 
See [Connecting C# Application To MS Access Database](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c56872/connecting-C-Sharp-application-to-ms-access-database/) also for usage.